# Global variable in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Ok guys I've been working on a sort of slider for JQtouch and I have two methods in my plugin, one that builds the slider on initiation and one that rebuilds it on rotation. I use a variable called "count" that holds the number of the current slide. My issue is, I lose the variable when ever the mobile device is rotated and the "rotate" method is called.

I defined the count variable in my settings as "1" and it seems that when the rotate method is called it takes the default set "1" instead of the current slide number. Here's my plugin code; it's very long. Basically everything that is happening in my init: method, all of the swiping and sliding changing of the "count" variable doesn't carry over to the "rotate" method.

```
(function ($) {
    var empty = {};
    var settings = {
        count: 1,
    };
    var methods = {
        init: function (options, callback, defaults) {
            var options = $.extend({},
            settings, options || {});
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                if (options.height) {
                    mHeight = options.height;
                } else {
                    mHeight = $(window).height();
                }
                mWidth = $(window).width();
                mAmount = $('.swiper', this).length;
                amount = $('.swiper', this).length;
                holdWidth = mWidth * options.amount;
                $('.swiper', this).height(mHeight);
                $(this).height(mHeight);
                $('.swiper', this).width(mWidth);
                $(this).width(holdWidth);
                $('.swipe_slide', this).width(holdWidth);
                $('.swipe_slide', this).height(mHeight);
                $('.swiper', this).each(function (i) {
                    var nwidth = mWidth * i;
                    $(this).css('left', nwidth);
                });
                $('.swipe_slide', this).swipe(function (evt, data) {
                    var amount = $('.swiper', this).length; // alert($($this).attr('id'));
                    if (data.direction == 'left') { //alert('count: '+options.count+" amount: "+options.amount);
                        if (options.count != amount) {
                            moveWidth = options.count * -mWidth;
                            $('.swipe_slide', $this).css("left", moveWidth);
                            options.count++
                        } else {
                            return
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (options.count != 1) {
                            moveWidth = moveWidth + mWidth;
                            $('.swipe_slide', $this).css("left", moveWidth);
                            options.count--
                        } else {
                            return
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        rotate: function (options, callback, defaults) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var options = $.extend({},
            settings, options || {});
            alert(options.count);
            return this.each(function () {
                if (options.height) {
                    mHeight = options.height;
                } else {
                    mHeight = $(window).height();
                }
                mWidth = $(window).width();
                mAmount = $('.swiper', this).length;
                amount = $('.swiper', this).length;
                holdWidth = mWidth * mAmount;
                $('.swiper', this).height(mHeight);
                $(this).height(mHeight);
                $('.swipe_slide', this).height(mHeight);
                $('.swiper', this).width(mWidth);
                $(this).width(holdWidth);
                $('.swipe_slide', this).width(holdWidth);
                $('.swiper', this).each(function (i) {
                    var nwidth = mWidth * i;
                    $(this).css('left', nwidth);
                });
                newMoveWidth = options.count * $(window).width();
                alert(options.count);
                alert(newMoveWidth); //$('.swipe_slide',$this).css( "left" , 0 );
            });
        }
    }
    $.fn.jCarousel = function (method, options) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.jModalbox');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Bad indentation = can't tell where your extra ```}``` is.

Comment: I had a feeling something would fall off when I copy and pasted it. I tried to remove some frivolous comments and things that have no effect on the plugin that may have effected the copy and paste.

Comment: I have formatted your code, using http://jsbeautifier.com/ Bookmark it.

Comment: I did not vote on this question at all yet but you should [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) if you're complaining about always getting down-voted.  Also, complaining about down-votes, complaining about comments, complaining about lack/quality of answers, and any off-topic comments within your post also tend to trigger lots of retaliatory voting.  If you want to discuss why you're getting lots of down-votes, it would be best to do it over in meta.stackoverflow.com instead of as an addendum to your question.

Comment: Besides formatting, you've also included quite a lot of code. As a guideline, if you see a scroll bar in your code snippet, you are probably posting too much code.

Comment: I appreciate the help and responses, I posted all of the code to help people understand the context of my problem. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed this, your problem is you're changing the value of count in the `extended` options, a local variable.  These changes won't propagate back up to `settings` like you think unless you pass `settings` as the target.  That might not be exactly what you want, but I'm pretty sure it should get you headed in the right direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/DTnW8/